# Unknown command 'saveenv' error in U-Boot

Tags: u-boot

I have a prebuilt image of the U-Boot. I can change the configıration using the `setenv` command. But, I can't save the current environment variables as the `saveenv` command is not recognized by the U-Boot. Also, there is no command called `saveenv` in the help list. U-Boot version is **2020.01**. Other things such as booting works well.

- What would be the reason for it?
- Is there another way to save the environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple. The prebuilt image was compiled without support to the `saveenv` command. If you have the chance to recompile the U-Boot, you can find it in `menuconfig` screen. Just go to the `Command Line Interface -> Environment Commands` and enable the `saveenv`.

I guess that there isn't an alternative way to save your current environment. You may want to search more on it.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I verified in the menuconfig that saveenv IS enabled. Using U-Boot 2020.01 in Petalinux 2020.1 workflow.

Comment: @kmalarski Did you successfully recompile to the executable binary?

Comment: Yes, and I made the test of adding another U-Boot command that also did not appear available after compilation. I saw Petalinux recompiling U-Boot and I packaged the BOOT.BIN with --force. IDK, maybe the problem lays in some Petalinux misconfiguration...

Comment: @kmalarski It may be overwriting your configuration. Did you try compiling the u-boot separately?